# Overleaf - Set header for only first page (and not all pages)

Tags: latex

I only want to set a header for only my first page. This is within overleaf.

**My Attempt:**

```
\fancyhead[L]{}

\fancyhead[R]{ \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

This issue is that this sets the header for all pages.

**How do I set the header to only be applicable for the first page and not all the pages?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define a custom style. Here with the name `firstpage`:

```
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
    \fancyhead[L]{}    
    \fancyhead[R]{ \includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}
}
```

Then use it on desired page:

```
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
```

Comment: What about the resulting white space on the following pages? How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @polar there is no whitespace. Something else must be causing this...